# How would one become a Lord of the Nine Hells?

Tags: dnd-5e

Basically, I've read all the lore surrounding devils and demons in d&d and I was wondering if this was possible.

I thought that the best process would to be a Warlock with the Fiend Patron, become powerful enough to make deals on your own then gain enough souls to extend your lifetime indefinitely.

After you've done this with the help of a Wizard you would spend years attempting to summon a devil. You'd then trade souls you'd acquired from pacts for its help in advancing in the demon world and gaining more power.

Rinse and repeat with the souls of people you'd roped into a cult or religion and traded with various devils until you have a substantial amount of power.

From there I guess you'd plane shift to one of the Nine Hells and defeat as many demons you can to show your prowess in battle, get sworn in as the aide of a high ranking devil and eventually usurp them and take their title.

Finally you'd use this power and devils you have bonded to you from your pacts to challenge one of the Lords?

This might be entirely wrong but I was thinking over if it was possible at all.

Comment: If you're actual question is *"how would one become a Lord of the Nine Hells"* could you edit the body of your question in such a way that it asks the same thing? I'm reading the body text as a "would this idea work" kind of question which is totally different from a "how can I achieve this goal" kind of question. Or if you are actually asking whether your idea would work, could you edit the title to ask something more along those lines.

Comment: None of this is defined, it'll be setting dependent and require working with your GM.  I'm afraid this question can't have a good answer here as a result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why wouldn't it be?

If your plan makes sense and follows a path true to the D&D universe, then it can be done.

There is no rule governing this. It has to do purely with your imagination and role playing. Like you said, if by somewhat following the lore and making up a long term badass plan, you think it is possible to take on hell, then do it!

Answer (score 3):

DnD-3.5 had the *Manual of the Planes* describing some of the events in the Nine Hells. You can "simply" kill one of the lords, take its place and then not-die. Some quotes from the book are below.

*From "Manual of the Planes", a 3.5e book:*

> ... Bel betrayed the former Lord
>   of the First, Zariel, for his current position. ...
>   While Bel has succeeded where many failed before him, his
>   climb to power seems to be stalled now, since he does not enjoy
>   the support of other Lords of the Nine, except for possibly
>   Asmodeus.

and:

> ... However, in all the time that Asmodeus has ruled from
>   below, no revolt has ever succeeded in replacing the lord
>   of the ninth layer with a different devil, despite a ploy
>   designed by Asmodeus that once allowed his rivals to
>   think he had been dethroned.

I don't know if DnD-5e has a source book on the matter, so this is all the information I can give you.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, to which part did you comment, take the place of a lord or if 5e has a source book?

Comment: 5e does not yet have a source book on this matter.  Sorry if I was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this has a "right" mechanical answer. My sense is that it would be dictated by the setting and how all that stuff works in your game. Just as an exercise though, I can see a couple of ways to handle it.

First, it could work a lot like the Necros in The Chronicles of Riddick. You kill the current Lord and you get his/her stuff. In this case, killing the Lord while difficult might not be nearly as hard as keeping your position later.

Second, the Lordship could be based on being attuned to the magical nature of that level of Hell. Taking over means getting enough support (followers, magical energy, whatnot) to attune yourself to that level which would necessarily oust the current ruler.

There are lots of other ways to deal with this as well. Probably a number of them documented in supplements. Regardless, I'd never make the solution a purely mechanical issue. Becoming one of the Lords of the Nine Hells ought to be very much a role-playing and story shaped proposition.